# How do you find averages of numbers in multidimensional arrays from user input?

Tags: c#

This is my first attempt at creating a multidimensional array. I have the user enter the number of students in a class(the rows), and then have them enter the number of scores they will input(the columns). I now want to add all the scores of each individual student and find each of their grade averages. I can't figure out how to separate out the information for each individual student's data. Here is what I have so far:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int TotalStudents = 0;
        int TotalGrades = 0;
        int sum = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of students: ");
        TotalStudents = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of grades: ");
        TotalGrades = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int[,] scoresArray = new int[TotalStudents, TotalGrades];

        for (int i = 0; i < TotalStudents; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < TotalGrades; j++)
            {
            Console.Write("Please enter score {0} for student {1}:", j + 1, i + 1);
                scoresArray[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                sum = sum + Convert.ToInt32(scoresArray[i,j]);
            }

        double gradePercent = sum / (TotalGrades * 100);
        double gradePer100 = gradePercent * 100;
        string gradeLetter = "";

        if (gradePer100 >= 90)
        {
            gradeLetter = "A";
        }
        else if (gradePer100 >= 80 && gradePer100 < 90)
        {
            gradeLetter = "B";
        }
        else if (gradePer100 >= 70 && gradePer100 < 80)
        {
            gradeLetter = "C";
        }
        else if (gradePer100 >= 60 && gradePer100 < 70)
        {
            gradeLetter = "D";
        }
        else
        {
            gradeLetter = "F";
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nStudent average score is: " + gradePer100);
        Console.WriteLine("\nStudent will recieve a " + gradeLetter + " in the class.");

        Console.Write("\nPress the [ENTER] key to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question, and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 2-dimensional array like this :

```
var array = new int[TotalStudents, TotalGrades];
```

And then fill it:

```
for(int i = 0; i < TotalStudents; i++)
for(int j = 0; j < TotalGrades; j++)
{
    Console.Write("Please enter score {0} for student {1}",  j + 1, i + 1);
    array[i, j] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

If the scores are `double`s just change `new int[TotalStudents, TotalGrades]` to `new double[TotalStudents, TotalGrades]` and `Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())` to `Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine())`